# Looking for "des" binary?

Tags: linux, shell, des

I am unable to find the linux binary "des", which seems to exist according to this [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/des).

Or if someone has an alternate method, I am wanting to decrypt DES encrypted strings from the shell.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a Debian based distribution, you can look up which packages provide which files online using http://packages.debian.org. I just looked up `des` and can't find anything like this as an executable. Also, this is man page from section 7 which is not where command references usually lie. I don't think it is either.

As for doing DES encryption from the command line, a quick google gave me [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19426/openssl-equivalent-to-des-command-line).